# Running Heroku using webpack and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, heroku, webpack

Firstly for context, here is my file structure:

```
bundle.js
package.json
package-lock.json
.gitignore
/.git
/node_modules
/src
    form.js
    form.css
    index.html
    json.js
```

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "transcriber-form-helper",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js ./src/form.js bundle.js"
},
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1"
  },
  "engines": {
          "node": "6.12.0"
  }
}
```

I have a working app (meaning if I run `index.html`, it runs correctly) which I have built with dependencies from `node.js`. I am also trying to use webpack but I don't fully understand it so I heavily suspect it is the source of my problems. From what I understand, `node.js` runs the `start` script on `npm start` and the `start` script runs `webpack` to compile `/src/form.js` and all its dependencies into an output `bundle.js`.

It is this `bundle.js` that is linked in my `index.html` as a script.

I am attempting to run this on a Heroku deploy. I created a brand new folder and `git init`. I committed all the files and ran a `heroku create` and subsequently pushed all with `git push heroku master`. Here is the result:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  6.12.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 6.12.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 6.12.0...
remote:        Detected package-lock.json: defaulting npm to version 5.x.x
remote:        Bootstrapping npm 5.x.x (replacing 3.10.10)...
remote:        npm 5.5.1 installed
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Skipping cache restore (new-signature)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        
remote:        > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /tmp/build_5f7197c56e4eae8677e4d73562940ae8/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
remote:        > node lib/post_install.js
remote:        
remote:        added 392 packages in 9.621s
remote: 
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        Clearing previous node cache
remote:        Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (nothing to cache)
remote: 
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 24.9M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v9
remote:        https://calm-beyond-56449.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
```

As far as I can understand it, nothing is clearly wrong, right?

The following is the `Heroku logs --tail` immediately after deploying.

```
2017-11-23T16:39:06.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user <my email here>
2017-11-23T16:39:48.456625+00:00 app[api]: Release v9 created by user <my email here>
2017-11-23T16:39:48.456625+00:00 app[api]: Deploy b38385b7 by user <my email here>
2017-11-23T16:39:06.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-11-23T16:39:49.649609+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-11-23T16:39:52.613766+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-11-23T16:39:55.858825+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-23T16:39:55.858824+00:00 app[web.1]: > node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js ./src/form.js bundle.js
2017-11-23T16:39:55.858823+00:00 app[web.1]: > transcriber-form-helper@1.0.0 start /app
2017-11-23T16:39:55.858811+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-23T16:39:58.414268+00:00 app[web.1]: Hash: e0226ff21cf9f346ae14
2017-11-23T16:39:58.414289+00:00 app[web.1]: Time: 1450ms
2017-11-23T16:39:58.414286+00:00 app[web.1]: Version: webpack 3.8.1
2017-11-23T16:39:58.414292+00:00 app[web.1]: bundle.js  299 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
2017-11-23T16:39:58.414291+00:00 app[web.1]:     Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
2017-11-23T16:39:58.414294+00:00 app[web.1]:    [1] ./src/json.js 9.42 kB {0} [built]
2017-11-23T16:39:58.414296+00:00 app[web.1]:    [3] ./node_modules/style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader!./src/form.css 1.01 kB {0} [built]
2017-11-23T16:39:58.414294+00:00 app[web.1]:    [0] ./src/form.js 2.68 kB {0} [built]
2017-11-23T16:39:58.414298+00:00 app[web.1]:    [4] ./node_modules/css-loader!./src/form.css 474 bytes {0} [built]
2017-11-23T16:39:58.414299+00:00 app[web.1]:     + 4 hidden modules
2017-11-23T16:39:58.558119+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-11-23T16:39:58.542644+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

It appears to have crashed. Running `Heroku ps: scale web=1` and subsequently `Heroku open` results in an error:

`An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.`

Additionally I have run `heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false` to include devDependencies.

Not sure if any other files are relevant to the problem but I'll include small excerpts of what I think is the connection stuff in each file:

`form.js`:

```
var templates = require('./json.js');
var $ = require('jquery');
require('style-loader!css-loader!./form.css');
```

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<html>
        <head>
                <title>Pejman's TranscribersOfReddit form helper</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <h1>/r/TranscribersOfReddit form helper</h1>
                <hr><br>

                <div id="form"></div>
                <br>
                <div id="form_content"></div>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" id="btn_generate" value="Generate" />
                <input type="submit" id="btn_reset" value="Reset" />
                <br><br>
                <textarea rows=10 cols=80 id="output"></textarea>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" id="btn_copy" value="Copy to Clipboard" />

                <script src="../bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```